# How can I see / change MySQL connection timeout settings?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java program. When I log in, after ~600,000 milliseconds (I actually tried several times, and it is always ~600,000. That is why I think there is somewhere set up a timeout for 600,000 miliseconds.) My database connection crashes and my program no longer works (it always needs to be connected to database). It gives me `Communication link failure` error. I Here are my mysql connection settings:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class mysqlconnect {
    Connection conn = null;
    public static Connection ConnectDb()    {
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://server_name/database_name","user_name","user_password");
            return conn;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cant connect to db");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding `?autoReconnect=true` & `tcpKeepAlive` to my code, but no luck. Is there any way to go to phpmyadmin and change some setting there (increase the timeout time)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 999999;//or anything you want
```

From mysql command line that will increase the timeout value. To be able to see the value:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
```

Comment: Sorry i dont understand , i must write this in my db_config file or somewhere in phpmyadmin

Comment: save those codes in a sql file and execute it or execute it via Java statement or execute it via copying it directly into mysql command line or toad for mysql or mysql workbench. [How to use mysql command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html)

Comment: it gives me this error - `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation` , i think ill need to get a better access privileges for this

Answer (score 7):

You can make this request to show your timeout in MySql

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect_timeout';
```

Next you can update it to 60 secondes for exemple

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=60;
```

If the problem is the Query you can use  [`Statement.setQueryTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks, its almost the same method as the post below you, but since that guy posted first i picked him as answer

Answer (score 5):

You can set `wait_timeout` `NET_read_timeout` and `connect_timeout` for resolve the problem in following way.

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout';
SET SESSION wait_timeout = 999999;`

`SHOW variables LIKE 'NET_read_timeout';
SET SESSION   net_read_timeout = 1000;`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect_timeout';
SET GLOBAL   connect_timeout = 1000;`

Comment: Could you also post an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I tipically do it with either one of the following ways:

1) Edit the my.ini file. This file is tipically located on C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

```
[mysqld]
interactive_timeout=2147483
wait_timeout=2147483
```

(max value is 2147483 for Windows and 31536000 in other OS)

After that, restart the machine

2) Include the wait time out parameter in the JDBC url. Here's a JDBC URL taken from my code

jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORT/DATABASE_NAME?autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH',interactive_timeout=2147483,**wait_timeout=2147483**