# How to fetch MYSQL connection time

Tags: mysql, time, connection

How to find out MYSQL connection time not `connection_timeout`?

I am able to find out the connection timeout value using

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'connect_timeout'
```

But I am not able to get the variable for connection time.

Comment: What means: "But I am not able to variable for connection time". Not able to change the timeout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i see / change MySQL connection timeout settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16192410/3664960) or [How can I change the default Mysql connection timeout when connecting through python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14726789/3664960)